# Running mysql without password and default user in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Currently, I start mysql 5.7 by

`mysql -u root -p`

then type the password.

Is there a way to allow to run `mysql` only (i.e., without `-u root -p`) and it login as root?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

There is the utility `mysql_config_editor`, which will help create the file `.myLogin.cnf` for you, which will be able to store login credentials.

What you'll then be doing is to store the encrypted password for the root user in that file.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you add default username and Password to `my.cnf`

[client]

```
 user            = root
 password        = yourpass
```

Then, you will be able to login as

```
shell>   mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 24
Server version: 5.7.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please specify, why do you have to do so?

1. You want to use it in shell script
2. or command line

Check this out
https://serverfault.com/questions/563714/allow-linux-root-user-mysql-root-access-without-password